# vertx circuitbreaker never closes again

Tags: rx-java, vert.x, circuit-breaker

I have a problem with my circuitBreaker. If I spam requests to my service the circuit properly `OPEN`'s and resolve's with a timeout error. After my set timeout the circuit goes in `HALF_OPEN` state - everything as it should be.
But from here the circuit never closes again. Every request made will result in an error and immediately opening the circuit again.

I use the cb to communicate between my services via the vertx eventBus like this:

```
return this.circuitBreaker.rxExecuteCommandWithFallback(
  future -> this.vertx.eventBus().rxSend("myEvent", myBody)
    .subscribe(
      data -> future.complete(data.body().toString()),
      err -> future.fail(err.getMessage())
    ), Throwable::getMessage);
```

my circuitBreaker options:

```
return new CircuitBreakerOptions()
  .setMaxFailures(10)
  .setTimeout(2000L)
  .setResetTimeout(5000L)
  .setMaxRetries(2)
  .setFallbackOnFailure(true);
```

Is my config wrong? do I maybe use the rxified API wrong?

**edit**
if I run my code inside docker containers i just get the error:
`io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: operation timeout`

if I start the application locally I see that PG/SQL actually throw's an `sorry, too many clients` exception. this would certainly explain why the circuit is still opened, but since I already close my client on success and error I don't really understand why this is happening.

--

it seems that my current way of closing connections after a request is false. when i check my database connections via `SELECT  * FROM pg_stat_activity where state = 'idle'` I can see that no requests actually terminate's properly.

my java code to execute a db query looks like this:

```
final AsyncSQLClient client = PostgreSQLClient.createShared(vertx, getConnectionData(), "mypool");
return client
  .rxGetConnection()
  .flatMap(conn -> conn.rxQuery(sql))
  .map(res -> {
    client.rxClose();
    return res;
  })
  .doOnError(err -> {
    client.rxClose();
  });
```

i use `io.vertx:vertx-mysql-postgresql-client:3.4.1` as a driver

Comment: It seems that in the half-state, the circuit breaker checks the interaction, which still fails. Do you have the exception message returned in this case?

Comment: just added the exceptions

Comment: So the circuit breaker behaves correctly, it's the PG/SQL client that is failing under the hood. Can you share this code?

Comment: yes you were right, my sql connections code seems to be broken, I added an example

Comment: rxClose() return a Single, you need to _subscribe_ on it:

return client
  .rxGetConnection()
  .flatMap(conn -> conn.rxQuery(sql))
  .doOnTerminate(() -> 
    client.rxClose().subscribe();
  });

Comment: Did you find the cause of the problem? @Markus

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I did in the end, but I'm pretty sure that I made mistakes in not calling `.subscribe()`